# Manual binding doesn't work

Tags: binding, ember.js

I have a strange behavior with the manual binding:

```
Ember.bind(App, "value", "App.wife.value");
```

The bound value isn't updated when the source is updated:

```
App.wife.set('value', 2); // App.value isn't updated
```

But when the bound value is updated, the source is updated:

```
App.set('value', 4); // App.wife.value is updated
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wooandoo/ZN9Sg/1/

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Hum, it seems like Ember.bind() indeed does not work with global path.

Using `Ember.bind(App, 'value', 'wife.value')` seems to work. Perhaps there is a bug.

Comment: thanks. A strange bug! I create another test (http://jsfiddle.net/wooandoo/ZN9Sg/2/): Ember.bind(App.container, "value", "App.wife.value") works. So global path works... sometimes.

Comment: Hm, perhaps this is just because in the original example, this is a special case, declaring a binding on the global App.